# Issues in writing data to a file in unix using python script

Tags: python

My Code is working perfectly when I am writing data into the target file using Python in Unix.

However, if I open the target file in Unix with vi mode and at the same time code is writing data into it, then it is skipping writing of data into the target file(not facing any error or code failure) till the time target file is being opened.

Below is a simple sample of my code:

```
import csv


with open('filename.txt', 'ab') as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerow([some data])
```

Please let me know if there is any way to keep writing data into file even if it is being used by some other process(the same way Unix shell script do)

Comment: What you expect? That vi updates automatically when the file changes? Also vi may be locking the file, but I'm not sure if vi does that.

Comment: My guess is that the file is being updated but as vim buffer is keep in memory you don't see the cahnge until you reread the file

Answer (score 0):

You are facing an Unix issue, not a Python one. There are cases where OS decides to lock you out. Spontaneous cases are rare though. It also depends on what program is writing a file. You can request the lock from your program too if you want.
However, when the file is released by another process your buffers should be written. What the result will be though, well, you should try and see..

You should be able to override the default behaviour by changing the flags on the file descriptor using the fcntl module.

It may even suffice to use low-level IO functions from os module instead of Python's file object. You can try os.open(), os.write() and os.close() first, and reading and changing flags later if the first solution does not work.

You can also try playing with Python buffering, changing the buffer argument of the open() function and turning it off completely by starting Python in unbuffered mode.

```
python -u
```